# ruby module inside module

Tags: ruby, module

I have a ruby module which includes many other modules. Here's a quick example:

```
module Foo

  module Bar
  end

  module Baz
  end

end
```

except, I have like 6-7 modules inside Foo module. Is there a way I can put Bar/Baz in separate file but still get the same behavior? Right now all my code is inside 1 file, very unorganized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define them like this, each in a separate file:

```
# foo.rb
module Foo
end

# foo_bar.rb
module Foo::Bar
end

# foo_baz.rb
module Foo::Baz
end
```

NB. You will need to define the `Foo` module *before* being able to define modules such as `Foo::Bar` with this notation.

Or you could just put them in differently named files in the format they're currently in and it should still work:

```
# foo_bar.rb
module Foo
  module Bar
  end
end

# foo_baz.rb
module Foo
  module Baz
  end
end
```

Comment: @PragmaOnce note that you can only use `module Foo::Bar` if you've _already_ defined `Foo` with `module Foo`, otherwise you'll get an error.