# Using methods from one Ruby module in another

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I've extracted some cross-cutting concerns such as getting a database connection, logging and application configuration into separate modules in my Ruby application. I can include them in classes that require those services. So far, so good.

My problem is that the database connection module requires logging and application configuration functionality, so ideally I'd like it to make use of the existing modules that provide these services, but I don't know how to achieve this. As you can see below, at the moment the code in the database connection module isn't very DRY.

**connection.rb**

```
module Connection
  def connection
    Connection.connection
  end

  def self.connection
    @connection ||= begin

      # Should use Configuration module here
      config = YAML.load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'config.yml'))
      @connection = Mysql2::Client.new(config['database'])
      @connection.query_options.merge!(symbolize_keys: true)
      @connection
    rescue Mysql2::Error => err

      # Should use Logging module here
      logger = Logger.new($stdout)
      logger.error "MySQL error: #{err}"
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end
```

**configuration.rb**

```
module Configuration
  def config
    Configuration.config
  end

  def self.config
    @config ||= YAML.load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'config.yml'))
  end
end
```

**logging.rb**

```
module Logging
  def logger
    Logging.logger
  end

  def self.logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new($stdout)
  end
end
```

Is there a way for my database connection module to be able to use the methods provided by the other two modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, modules can act as *mixins* from which other modules can inherit. If you want to use the instance methods of a module, you have to mix in that module. This is achieved by the [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include) method:

```
module Connection
  include Configuration, Logging
end
```

Now, `Connection` inherits from `Configuration` and `Logging`, and instances of `Connection` can thus use all methods from `Configuration` and `Logging` in addition to the ones of `Connection` (and `Object`, `BasicObject`, `Kernel`).

If you also want access to those instance methods within `Connection`'s module methods, then you need to additionally `extend` the `Connection` with `Configuration` and `Logging` as well:

```
module Connection
  extend Configuration, Logging
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jörg. I discovered that I had to prepend the method name with the module name in order to make it work e.g. within the `Connection` module `logger.error` becomes `Logging.logger.error` etc.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. The `Logging` module you posted contains a `Logging#logger` instance method which forwards to the `Logging::logger` module method. If you mix in the `Logging` module, you should be able to use that instance method. By the way: there is a method which automatically creates module methods for instance methods, so you don't have to write them by hand: [`Module#module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function).

Comment: That's what I thought, but if I don't prepend the module name, I get `undefined local variable or method 'config' for Connection:Module (NameError)` for the line `@connection = Mysql2::Client.new(config['database'])`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. You are trying to use the methods in a module method, not an instance method. Then it's `extend` instead of `include` of course.

Answer (score -1):

You could try `module` inside a `module`, So that you could use your existing methods between your modules.

there were few examples I could find

[module inside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361296/ruby-module-inside-module)

[extending ruby module inside another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662722/extending-a-ruby-module-in-another-module-including-the-module-methods)

and more about ruby modules [here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/modules_mixins.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)

HTH